# how to read every rows in excel and save in map

Tags: java, json, excel, apache-poi, bufferedreader

I want to read every row in the excel file and save in a map.

My input file will look something like this,

```
ID| Name|   details
 1| xx|     {
             "user":"xx",
             "email":"xxx@xxx.in"
             }
2|  yy|     {
            "user":"yy",
            "email":"yyy@xxx.in"
             }
```

I want to get the values in the excel based on the provided id. if i pass the value of 2, it should return the name and details corresponding to the id - 2.
so i tried to use map and key value as ID.

```
        String fileToParse = "D:\\InputData.xls";
    BufferedReader fileReader = null;

            String line = "";
            fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToParse));    
            line = fileReader.readLine();

            Map<Long, String> dataMap = new HashMap<Long, String>();

            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
            {      
                data dataTO = new data();
                String[] s = line.split("|");
                String value = s[1] + "," + s[2] + "," + s[3];
                dataMap.put(Long.parseLong(s[0]), value);   
            }
            long id = 2;                
            String val = dataMap.get(id);
            String url = val.split(",")[0];
            String input = val.split(",")[1];
```

Also my data class will have getter and setter methods for the values in excel file like this,

```
public class data {
private int id;

private String name;

private String details;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}
```

}

The above code is working fine for normal string value but if i provide Json value in the details field, the value in map is saved as

```
1|Url 01|"{
```

instead of whole json value.
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem? or is there any other approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small addition to your input reading:

```
String hline;
while( (hline = fileReader.readLine()) != null){
     line = hline;
     while( ! hline.endsWith( "}" ) ){
         hline = fileReader.readLine();
         line += hline;
     }
```

This should be put into a separate method, but I leave this to you - I don't want to change too much.

Comment: hi @laune. Thanks for your code. i added your code in same method and it really worked but i am getting null pointer exception. After reading the fourth column, it is trying to read the next column and getting null value. Can you please help me to solve this ?

Comment: json values are qualified by extra delimiter("), my json is displayed as  "{"
"username"":""xxx"",
""pwd"":""yyy""
}"|"{"
""username"":""xxx"",
""pwd"":""yyy""
}", so it returned null pointer exception. After removing the extra delimiter, this code solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using a library like Apache POI for reading excel file. You can find details about reading and writing to a file here: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook

Pros are that you don't have to try to understand the format of the xls file.

You can simply add the dependency to your project if you are using any dependency management build system or add the jar file directly to your project.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.11